Which character is this? Pink helmet with an eagle - white outfit - yellow scarf - anime, I think
My nephew dressed up as this character for Halloween and I have no idea who he is.

An image would help a lot. (Of just the clothing, if you don't want to post an image of your nephew.) Also, wouldn't your nephew know who the character is?

I’m voting to close this question because it does not seem to be about science fiction or fantasy.

Even an artist's rendition in MSPaint would be a big help here

https://ms.yugipedia.com//thumb/a/af/MimiImimi-AdvisorM.png/800px-MimiImimi-AdvisorM.png - https://yugipedia.com/wiki/Mimi_Imimi?

Pink Gokiager? https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/powerrangers/images/a/a3/Gokaiger_%28Team%29.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/1000?cb=20190824174439

Could be White Swan from Chōjin Sentai Jetman

White suit. Pink helmet. Bird motif that could be mistaken for an eagle. Yellow scarf. Female character, but I'm not judging your nephew for that.

Are you able to locate a photo that doesn't look like you took it with the camera on your fridge?

@valorum My choice of refrigerator pinups is my business...
